using passed argument in javascript function constructor
Here I'm trying to use a function constructor and then use that constructor to create a circle object.
const Circle1 = Function('radius,centerX,centerY',`
this.radius = radius;
this.centerX = centerX;
this.centerY = centerY;
this.draw = function(){
  console.log('drawing circle with radius ${this.radius}');
};
`);


const mycircle = new Circle1(5,10);
mycircle.draw();

When I run the code the result I see on the console is like this:
drawing circle with radius undefined

Is there a way that I can use those arguments passed to the function?
I tried to reach the value as ${radius} or ${this.radius} but both of them give the result as undefined. I was expecting to see the actual radius value.

Why are you making a function with the Function constructor? Except for some very unusual situations, that's never a good idea.

"trying to learn javascript"

Well that's a noble cause, but you must understand that there's absolutely no reason to do this. You can make functions perfectly well with function expressions or plain function declarations, and you don't need to worry about some odd behavioral aspects of using the Function constructor.

Well thats a good advice, thank you.

"trying to learn javascript" go work your way through a tutorial or 5. Javascript has a lot of rough edges: stuff that technically works but is a terrible idea, and the Function constructor is a case in point. Any decent tutorial will get you to a point where you can do basic programming in JS.

Although all the comments about not needing to do this are right, the actual problem is that you are using a template literal for the function body, but you want to create another literal for the console log. So you need to use the back tick there as well, but you also need to escape the $ or it will apply to the outer literal and so the this.radius will mean nothing (in that context).


const Circle1 = Function('radius,centerX,centerY', `
    this.radius = radius;
    this.centerX = centerX;
    this.centerY = centerY;
    this.draw = function(){
      console.log(\`drawing circle with radius \${this.radius}\`);
    };
    `);
    
const mycircle = new Circle1(5, 10);
mycircle.draw();



